# C++ Why can't I throw an abstract class?

Tags: c++, throw

I have a pure virtual class, `BaseClass`, with no data members and a protected constructor. It exists only to provide the interface for a subclass (which is templated). I want just about all the functionality implemented in the base class. Functions that operate on these typically would return `BaseClass&`, to allow convenient chaining of operations.

All well and good until I try to throw an instance, returned by reference from one of the functions. In short, I am throwing a reference to an abstract class, but I'm secure in the knowledge that it's guaranteed to be a fully constructed child class instance with all virtual functions intact. That's why the `BaseClass` constructor is protected. I'm compiling against a C++14 compiler. It's refusing to allow me to throw an abstract class.

One of the main points of the class is that I can construct a subclass, immediately call functions on it to add information, and then throw it, all in one fell swoop:

```
throw String<72>().addInt(__LINE__).addText("mom says no"); //does not compile
```

but `addText()`, very reasonably, returns `BaseClass&`, and the compiler refuses.

How do I? Moving all the member functions into the subclass seems obscene. I can hack around it by static casting the whole expression before the throw:

```
throw static_cast<String<72&>( //works, ugly
   BaseClassString<72>().addText(where).addText(why).addText(resolution));
```

and even create a macro to hide the ugly mechanics and ensure some safety, but am I missing something? This seems like case of C++ preventing a perfectly workable technique.

Comment: You are not allowed to create objects of an abstract type.

Comment: I didn't. It's not even possible, because the constructor is protected. All created objects are of one of the fully defined subclass types.

Comment: `throw` takes a copy.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw - "First, copy-initializes the exception object from expression [...]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the derived class `throw` itself through a `virtual void Throw() const` member function.  That would eliminate the casting at the callsite.  The principle being similar to having a *virtual clone* function for polymorphic copying.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::get;
using std::holds_alternative;
using std::ostream;
using std::ostringstream;
using std::string;
using std::variant;
using std::vector;

class Abc {
    using info_t = variant<int, string>;
    vector<info_t> v;
    virtual auto subtext() const -> string = 0;
public:
    virtual ~Abc();
    Abc() = default;
    Abc(Abc const&) = default;
    auto addInt(int) -> Abc&;
    auto addText(string) -> Abc&;
    virtual void Throw[[noreturn]]() const = 0;
    virtual void print(ostream&) const;
};

Abc::~Abc() = default;

auto Abc::addInt(int value) -> Abc& {
    v.push_back(value);
    return *this;
}

auto Abc::addText(string value) -> Abc& {
    v.push_back(value);
    return *this;
}

void Abc::print(ostream& out) const {
    if (auto st = subtext(); !st.empty())
        out << st << "\n";

    for (auto&& x : v) {
        if (holds_alternative<int>(x)) {
            out << get<int>(x) << "\n";
        } else if (holds_alternative<string>(x)) {
            out << get<string>(x) << "\n";
        } else {
            out << "(unknown type)\n";
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
class Concrete : public Abc {
    T data;
    auto subtext() const -> string override {
        ostringstream ss;
        ss << data;
        return ss.str();
    }
public:
    Concrete(T value) : data{value} {}
    void Throw[[noreturn]]() const override { throw *this; }
};
struct allow_ctad_t;
Concrete(allow_ctad_t)->Concrete<void>;

int main() {
    try {
        Concrete(1000).addInt(__LINE__).addText(__FILE__).addText("Just testing!").Throw();
    } catch (Abc const& ex) {
        ex.print(cout);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't accept this as the answer because it doesn't actually answer the question, but that's an idea solution and I'm annoyed I didn't think of it myself.

Answer (score 8):

> Why can't I throw an abstract class?

Due to [[except.throw]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/except.throw#3)

> **/3** Throwing an exception **copy-initializes** ([dcl.init], [class.copy.ctor]) **a temporary object**, called the exception object.
>
> **/5** When the thrown object is a class object, the constructor selected for the copy-initialization as well as the constructor selected for a copy-initialization considering the thrown object as an lvalue shall be non-deleted and accessible, even if the copy/move operation is elided ([class.copy.elision]).

Comment: To be extra explicit, when `throw` takes the copy, that copy would produce an instance of the base class, and that is not possible because the base class is abstract.

Comment: Got it. All throw sees is "reference to X" and it has no mechanism to determine that the actual object is of a subtype. I was hoping that, because it is a reference, the actual underlying type would prevail, but it's in essence copy-slicing. If I cast the reference down, it works as intended. Thanks.